# Convert all jpg images to webp Magick

Tags: imagemagick

how can I convert almost all images from jpg format to webP format if they are already on the server?
I used the command

```
magick convert. * jpg .webp
```

but I don't think it's ok because it would create images over them. How should we proceed as correctly as possible so as not to duplicate the images?

Is there an easier way to do this since I have all the images on the server?

Comment: ImageMagick will not delete your jpg images after creating webp images. If you are on IM 7, then use `magick` and not `magick convert`. However, you cannot use the command you have now. First you have a space between * and jpg. Second, all jpg input images would end up with the same .webp output name. You should use `magick mogrify` to convert a folder of jpg to an existing empty folder that will contain all your webp images. Then delete the folder of jpg images.